# mysql read ä/ö/ü with dots (on top)

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I have a mysql database charset utf8_general_ci. All fields are utf8_general_ci to.
And I read with php the DB to this header

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

but a/o/u with dots (on top) are displayed as ?.

could somebody help me please?

Comment: Is the database connection also UTF-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make connection to MySQL server, query `SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci` first to set connection's encoding.

Example when using mysqli extension:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','user','password','database_name');
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci");
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT 'Ä/ä' AS data");
```